# Edittext - Move Start of Text

Tags: android, android-edittext

[image]

In this edittext I use, text written on it starts too left. How can I make it so it is moved more to the right? And... what is that black cursor at the left? It disappears for some reason if I set gravity to the center. Thanks a lot

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:hint="@string/hint_1"
    android:background="@drawable/shape" />
```

Comment: Please post your xml as well.

Comment: is Your test will static or user can remove it too .

Comment: have you used padding property ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to move right then you can use

```
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set position bye

```
editText1.setSelection(position)
```

May this will work

Another

```
etmsg.setText("test");
int position = etmsg.length();
Editable etext = etmsg.getText();
Selection.setSelection(etext, position);
```

Where etmsg is your Edittext

Answer (score 1):

You can set position by:

```
editText.setSelection(position)
```

so, to go to the beginning , use `editText.setSelection(0);`

Answer (score 0):

Use padding

```
android:paddingLeft = "5dp"
```